# Lua variable not updated in wrk

Tags: lua, wrk

I need to run a script in wrk to test my endpoint. My script is as followed:

```
thread_counter = 0
local thread_id = 1
setup = function (thread)
    thread_counter = thread_counter + 1
    thread_id = thread_counter
    print("thread_id 1 " ..thread_id)
end

request = function() 
    idx = math.random(200)
    print("thread_id 2 " ..thread_id)
...
end
```

I can see that thread_id is updated in the setup function, but not the request function. Why and how can I fix this?

Comment: You don't seem to be assigning to `thread_id` in `request`, so why would it be updated? Is `idx = math.random(200)` perhaps meant to be `thread_id = math.random(200)`?

Comment: The idea is that setup is called first by wrk, which will be given the value of the global variable thread_counter. Then when request is called, I will use the thread_id number. the line idx = math.random(200) is actually redundant in this question's context